# Are there any parallels between the Ones & the Skywalkers?

Tags: star-wars

[The Ones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ones) are composed of the Father, the Son, & the Daughter. The Skywalkers are composed of Anakin the father, Luke the son & Leia the daughter.

Are there any intentional parallels between the two in the Star Wars universe?

Comment: A father with a son and a daughter is a pretty common occurrence in families everywhere.

Comment: Are you looking for parallels, or things acknowledged by creators?

Comment: Honestly, I think there's a better place to look for a parallel: Kylo, Rey, and Han (assuming that Kylo and Rey are siblings or half-siblings through Han). Kylo is Dark Side, Rey is Light Side, Han is unaligned (though probably not a Force user). Kylo kills his father (which is what the Son was trying to do) and presumably will try to kill Rey (which is what the Son succeeded in doing).

Comment: Looking for parallels, in or out of universe, intentionally drawn by either the creators of the lore or by the will of the Force.

Comment: I have to give you a little more credit here, though. I watched some commentary by Filoni, and the whole thing is intended as a grand metaphor for “all six *Star Wars* films.” So, it’s perhaps more likely than I would have thought.

Answer (score 3):

### Not many

There are a few superficial similarities:

- They are both families of Force users.
- They both have a father, a son, and a daughter. It is possible that the Son and Daughter are twins.

However, these are fairly generic characteristics. The second is a pretty common family structure, and the first is more or less guaranteed by the general focus of the *Star Wars* films. There are more (and more *significant*) differences.

- The Daughter is a powerful Force user, the equal of the Son; Leia is an untrained Force Sensitive, and [arguably](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131672/why-didnt-vader-detect-the-force-in-leia) not as strong as Luke.
- The Son represented the Dark Side, the Daughter the Light Side, and the Father the Balance between them. Leia and Luke are both aligned with the Light Side, and Vader (the apparent Father analogue) flip-flopped between Light and Dark. This is entirely different from the dynamic among the Ones.
- The Son kills his sister. Luke does not. Again, this is an entirely different dynamic.

---

That said, while these apparent dissimilarities make me disinclined to interpret it in the specific manner suggested, there’s definitely something there. Dave Filoni’s [commentary](http://www.starwars.com/video/altar-of-mortis-episode-featurette) on the arc indicates that the events are meant to be broadly metaphorical of occurrences in “all six films.” It seems likely to me that the struggle between the Son and Daughter was meant to recall Anakin’s own internal struggle, but if any of the characters correspond to Anakin, it would be the Son (conflicted, falls to the Dark Side).

Answer (score 2):

**The Father and Anakin**

In the Clone Wars, episode 15, series 3 [Overlords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Overlords) we see Anakin arriving on the planet Mortis, where the One's live. The father reveals he is the only one who can keep the peace between his children- the son and daughter. He later states that, because he is aging, he wants Anakin to take over from him, as only the Chosen one could help maintain the balance of the force- from Mortis.

This could be seen as Anakin having parallels in ability and purpose
 to the father- both are the only ones who can maintain the balance of the force.

**The Son, The Daughter and Luke and Leia**

The Son and Daughter are both powerful force users, but on different sides of the force. The daughter is a manifestation of the light side, whereas the Son is of the dark side.

Luke is, very clearly, a Jedi, and therefore firmly set as a user of the light side of the force (see the events of the original trilogy, most notably Luke's declaration at the end of *Return of the Jedi*

> Luke: I'm a Jedi, like my father before me.

In [Bloodline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodline_(novel)), a recent novelisation about Princess Leia's life, describes a passage where she watches a hologram of herself murdering Jabba the Hutt.

> Narrator: They were on the sail barge, and these were the last moments of Jabba the hutt's life... with a kind of awe, Leia watched herself slaying the heavy chains around Jabba's neck. **The sheer strength it took to compress a Hutt's neck to the point of asphyxiation- she had summoned that from somewhere deep inside.** Remebered doing so; but found it almost unbelievable to witness. **Pure hatred had fueled her.**

It is clear from this that Leia was using the dark side to assist her killing of Jabba.

[A video discussing this can be seen here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUz1po8U8sg)

However, this is a slightly weaker comparison that the clear parallels that can be drawn between Anakin and the Father, as Leia is technically only a force-sensitive.

Ultimately, I'd say that the parallels are:
- Two siblings being on the "opposite sides" of the force (dark and light)
- A father figure- literally the father of the children- who maintains control

Whereas the weaknesses in this/ differences are:
 - Luke and Leia getting along, working together, remaining allied etc., wheras all the "One's" children did was fight
 - Anakin's inability to influence/control his children as Darth Vader.
[Trying to turn Luke to the Dark side]